# Find the values missing between two tables

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Pretty new to kql. Have a very basic question.

Say - I have two tables - Table1, Table2 which has a column named id.

What i am looking for is a query - to find the id's which are present in Table1 but not in Table2?

I saw set_differnce, where i am stuck is to generate the arrays to be passed to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a `leftanti`/`rightanti` `join`, or `!in`.

examples:

this returns a table with a column `x`, with the values `1,4,7,22,25,28`

```
let T1 = range x from 1 to 30 step 3;
let T2 = range y from 10 to 20 step 1;
T1
| join kind=leftanti T2 on $left.x == $right.y
```

and so does this:

```
let T1 = range x from 1 to 30 step 3;
let T2 = range y from 10 to 20 step 1;
T1
| where x !in((T2 | project y))
```